# Exit from emergency mode in Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I am new in Ubuntu and I have a problem to boot my system. I was running a program that my system was locked so I decided to shut down my system physically, actually the other keys didn't work. Then when I tried to start it again, I found myself in the emergency mood and I can't quit from this mood. I searched the net and I found that I should edit the etc/fstab. But my problem is that any command that I run here is known as wrong. Here you can see a screenshot of my labtop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may need to run a file system check. Use `fsck` from a Live USB/DVD.

Comment: DON'T edit /etc/fstab without a specific reason to do so. What exact error messages do you see in emergency mode? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Also, you forgot the screenshot. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your answer. I got the following error: `[ 0.058810] ACPI Error [-PPC] Namespace llokup failure, AE-ALREADY-EXISTS`

Comment: @heynnema, here you can see the error message [a link to the error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qgdKGU4St_vQvbMHiY6oWe86tUOLNsSQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are multiple things going on in your error link. Did you have a CD/DVD inserted into your CD/DVD drive at the time all of those messages occurred? I ask because it's logging errors against dev sr1, and that's your CD/DVD drive. I've modified my answer, can you please try and do it and report back?

Comment: @heynnema, No I didn't have any CD/DVD. I was just running a deep learning algorithm. Yes, I will try the way that proposed. Just I have access to the advanced options for Ubuntu and recovery mood. Is there any way that I can fix the problem from there?

Comment: @heynnema, thank you so much for your help. I tried the way that you suggested. In recovery mood, I typed `sudo fdisk -l`, then I found this message **partition 4 dose not start on physical sector boundary**. then I ran the command `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda10` that fixed all the problems in partiotion4. Many thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda9`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`