# Ubuntu not booting properly ufter update to new Ubuntu version

Tags: boot, 22.04, fstab

Hello here is my problem:

### Status:

I try to start my NAS-System (Odroid-H2-Hardware). It goes until start screen of ubuntu an then switches to the emergency mode:

```
[   0.2814999] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS. 
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 254561/15237120 files, 13095856/60918272 blocks
[   3.525335] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found (this is removed when not using the ubuntu usb)
[   3.525375] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through (this is removed when not using the ubuntu usb)
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Drücken Sie die Eingabetaste für Wartungsarbeiten (oder drücken Sie Strg+D, um fortzufahren)
```

### What I did before:

My system where working fine for >1 year.

1. I did add up a new backup software (veeam agent).
2. I setup a false configuration so it put the backup of the total file system (SSD 256GB + HDD 4TB to the ssd (until then everything was functional so i did notice a that point)
3. I could not join to xrdp anymore
4. I checked to fix xrdp and a some point noticed that the storage was full (could not install or update anything)
5. I tried to remove cache and reduce log-files in the process until i found out about the false backup
6. I deleted the backup and i could do backups again, but xrdp was not working
7. I did the version update from 22.04 to 22.04.3 (not sure about the versions, i had to `do-release-upgrade`
8. During the update I confirmed everything with yes
9. At some point it asked for a specific configuration file unfortunately I cannot remember which one. It said:

```
Configuration file 'xxxxxxx'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** xxxxxx (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

10. I believe I did 2nd Option (an I think this is the issue of the problem, but not sure)
11. Update finished, I startet an then landed in emergency mode
12. I already tried different workarounds and did them **again** for this post (see what "What I already tried")

### What I already tried:

#### Press Ctrl +D / Strg +D

If I press the first time `Ctrl +D` it states:

```
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
```

Nothing happends and the emergency mode is back
The 2nd or 3rd time I enter it it states in red:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued , but 'stop' is included in transaction).
```

At this point i also could not find to enter anything beyond so I had to reboot manually

#### Check the journal

I pressed `Enter` and typed `journalctl -xb` as advised. I don't know how I can post the journal here, so here are some warnings/failures If found, in order of appearance (Typed from the screen, so there maybe typo's) Note: I left out some referring to a USB-Hub and Ubuntu-USB I added later for diagnosis:

```
X86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Expanded resource Reserved due to conflict with PCI Bus 0000:00
device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
platform eisa.0: EISA: cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field
systemd-fstab-generator [298]: Moint point 0 is not a valid path, ignoring.
```

Add this point it started different jobs (in green) and some message started to repeat.

```
kernel: r1825: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
kernel: r1825 module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel (was displayed white)
systemd-udevd [356]: nvme0n1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1' failed with exit code 1.
systemd-udevd [368]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
systemd-udevd [357]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
mtp-probe [390]: checking bus1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2"
mtp-probe [390]: bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
systemd-udevd [359]: nvme0n1p1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/nvme0n1' failed with exit code 1.
systemmd[1]: Found device KINGSTON SA2000M8250G EFI\x20System\x20Partition.
```

I assumed the following failures where results of the before (for example could not mount xxx)

#### Checked for `x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS` (no the cause)

I searched for it and found [SGX disabled by BIOS message on Ubuntu 20.04 booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418992/sgx-disabled-by-bios-message-on-ubuntu-20-04-booting), but it seems to be not the cause

#### Checked for `Failed to start default target`

I searched for a solution here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482674 and here [Exit from emergency mode in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226523/exit-from-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu) and ended up doing this:

1. boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
2. open a `terminal` window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
3. type `sudo fdisk -l` Result is:

```
Festplatte /dev/loop0: 3,02 GiB, 3241230336 Bytes, 6330528 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 Bytes, 8 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop2: 63,45 MiB, 66531328 Bytes, 129944 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop3: 237,21 MiB, 248729600 Bytes, 485800 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop4: 73,88 MiB, 77463552 Bytes, 151296 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop5: 349,7 MiB, 366682112 Bytes, 716176 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop6: 485,52 MiB, 509100032 Bytes, 994336 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop7: 53,26 MiB, 55844864 Bytes, 109072 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/sda: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: TOSHIBA HDWQ140 
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 674F1DA9-7BE4-4BE1-A21B-0E3C773F0153

Gerät      Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1    2048 7814035455 7814033408  3,6T Linux RAID


Festplatte /dev/sdb: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: TOSHIBA HDWQ140 
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 60010EF4-38E2-4BC4-A6CF-85151FD5B036

Gerät      Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1    2048 7814035455 7814033408  3,6T Linux RAID


Festplatte /dev/nvme0n1: 232,89 GiB, 250059350016 Bytes, 488397168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: KINGSTON SA2000M8250G                   
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 94ADF3BF-029D-47A7-AC04-2731524D9021

Gerät           Anfang      Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI-System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 488396799 487346176 232,4G Linux-Dateisystem


Festplatte /dev/sdc: 7,45 GiB, 8000110592 Bytes, 15625216 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: Cruzer Blade    
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: dos
Festplattenbezeichner: 0x0fc98286

Gerät      Boot Anfang     Ende Sektoren Größe Kn Typ
/dev/sdc1  *      2048 15625215 15623168  7,4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Festplatte /dev/loop8: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 Bytes, 187776 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop9: 12,32 MiB, 12922880 Bytes, 25240 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Festplatte /dev/loop10: 452 KiB, 462848 Bytes, 904 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
```

3. identified the /dev/nvme0n1 device name as my "Linux Filesystem"
4. typed `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1`
5. got an error, searched for it and learned i have to use the partion insted
6. typed `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1` the result was:

```
fsck von util-linux 2.37.2
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
```

7. did not make any changes this time, typed `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`, the result was:

```
fsck von util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Durchgang 1: Inodes, Blöcke und Größen werden geprüft
Durchgang 2: Verzeichnisstruktur wird geprüft
Durchgang 3: Verzeichnisverknüpfungen werden geprüft
Durchgang 4: Referenzzähler werden überprüft
Durchgang 5: Zusammengefasste Gruppeninformation wird geprüft
/dev/nvme0n1p2: 254562/15237120 Dateien (0.4% nicht zusammenhängend), 13097910/60918272 Blöcke
```

8. reboot, no change afterwards

#### Check fstab

Next I checked stumbled upon these two posts: [Stuck in emergency mode and nothing works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works)

1. typed `cat /etc/fstab` (did not work as i was on the ubuntu-usb not displaying my actual fstab)
2. opened the etc folder of the ssd directly into terminal
3. typed `cat fstab`, here is the result:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=4c7afe94-e2be-488d-930a-80c72c771823 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=F0F9-771C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md0    /mnt/storage    ext4    defaults 0 2
bindfs#/mnt/storage/shares/niels /mnt/storage/nextcloud-bindfs/heimnetz-niels fuse force-user=root,force-group=root,create-for-user=smb,create-for-
group=smb,chgrp-ignore,chown-ignore,chmod-ignore 0 0
bindfs#/mnt/storage/shares/main /mnt/storage/nextcloud-bindfs/heimnetz-main fuse force-user=root,force-group=root,create-for-user=smb,create-for-group=smb,chgrp-ignore,chown-ignore,chmod-ignore 0 0
```

4. typed `blkid`, the result was:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="F0F9-771C" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="9532a5b1-7b6d-4788-8554-8208602710dc"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="4c7afe94-e2be-488d-930a-80c72c771823" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="06bed7c0-645d-4684-abce-f526a5746e26"
/dev/sda1: UUID="10f77fbe-8714-9c38-780e-3911509dfb79" UUID_SUB="79173ef2-be7b-248a-6d46-38b3aab64104" LABEL="niels-ODROID-H2:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="9f866313-e4ae-4bd2-bb78-4a4a41b04f86"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="10f77fbe-8714-9c38-780e-3911509dfb79" UUID_SUB="c4ab03ba-0e32-9575-c85e-bf0c1bba7cf6" LABEL="niels-ODROID-H2:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="fb90770c-5a63-4453-bd56-a1f16865e27a"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="UBUNTU 22_0" UUID="5624-662A" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0fc98286-01"
```

5. I checked which UUID in `/etc/fstab` does not appear in `blkid`  output, but I didn't find any.

###Started in Advanced Options boot menu ###
When choosing the Advanced Options in the boot menu I get 4 Options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-86-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-86-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic (recovery mode)
```

When I try the recovery mode (boot version) I come to the menu, but still be in the terminal. -> I cannot choose any option and have some weird graphic bug that displays one line or part of it of the terminal.
I somehow made it to get `dbkg` but not changed anything.

During startup I regnozied all lines where ok but 2. I made a slomotion video of it, it states the following:

```
[  OK  ] Mounted /mnt/storage/nextcloud-bindfs/heimnetz-nxxxx
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/storage/nextcloud-bindfs/heimnetz-nxxxx.
See 'systemctl status "mnt-storage-nextcloud\\x2dbindfs-heimnetz\\x2dniels.mount"' for details
[Depend] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

#### Where I am at the moment (TL:DR)

I managed to start in recovery mode and have access to all files, but I don't know how to proceed know. I think it is some more or less important config file. (like `fstab`).